# Is there any way to list all functions in a C library?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, libraries

I have a compiled lib in my /usr/lib/ directory which I would like to know what are all the available functions I can call using this lib. Is there any way to list them?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean that you'll know enough about them to actually use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On linux: `nm -D /usr/lib/libmylib.so`

The `-D` is needed for shared libraries. For a C++ library, run this through c++filt to produce more readable names: `nm -D /usr/lib/libmylib.so | c++filt`

You'll probably be better off trying to find the corresponding headers for the library; you'll need to include the headers anyway if you want to use most of the functions, or rewrite the function prototypes for the methods you're trying to call. The headers might also have documentation on what the function behavior is.